# Can't get manpath to work

Tags: man

I have a directory which contains man page files and some other files:

```
$ ls doc
cheatsheet.svg  colorschemes.md  config   howto-publish-a-release.md  ranger.1
ranger.desktop  ranger.pod   rifle.1  rifle.pod           tools
```

The two files of interest are `rifle.1` and `ranger.1`. I want to be able to do `man ranger` and view the manual entry for it. To this end, I add the location of `doc` to my `$MANPATH`

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/path/to/doc::/home/.opam/system/man:/home/.opam/system/man:/home/.opam/system/man
```

Where the last 3 entries used to exist in `$MANPATH` before I touched it. I also tried to set `$MANPATH` to `/path/to/doc` and remove everything else. In either case, when I issue the man command, I get an error

```
$ man ranger
No manual entry for ranger
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The manual pages must be organised into sections underneath a component of `MANPATH`. Pages in section 1 must be in the `man1` subdirectory

```
mkdir -p /tmp/man/man1        # /tmp/man is the MANPATH component
cp ranger.1 /tmp/man/man1/    # Put ranger.1 into the man1 subdirectory

MANPATH=/tmp/manman ranger    # Override the MANPATH for the example
```

You could try `ln -s . man1`, which creates a `man1` "subdirectory" that is actually the same as your current directory (`doc`), and then your example should work:

```
MANPATH=/path/to/doc man ranger
```